# how to handle Alexa Echo Show built-in intent

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

According to the echo show documentation, ONLY the AMAZON.PreviousIntent, and AMAZON.MoreIntent have to be handled by the skill developer.

I've written the following code for them, but Alexa says an error occurred when invoking both previous and next intents on the echo show.

```
SpeechletResponse speechletResp = new SpeechletResponse();
DelegateDirective dd = new DelegateDirective();
List<Directive> directiveList = new ArrayList<>();
directiveList.add(dd);
speechletResp.setDirectives(directiveList);
speechletResp.setNullableShouldEndSession(null);
return speechletResp;
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @aberger i'm getting an invalid request error

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is curring here:

```
speechletResp.setNullableShouldEndSession(null);
```

You should set if the session will end or not, with a true or false.